# How to pass a document-node into an eval/invoke

Tags: marklogic

I have code like:

```
let $evalParams := map:map(
    <map:map
        xmlns:map='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map'>
        <map:entry>
            <map:key>document</map:key>
            <map:value>{$doc}</map:value>
        </map:entry>
    </map:map>)
let $resultDocument := xdmp:eval($transformCode, $evalParams)
```

where in the $transform code it checks for a document-node:

```
declare variable $document as document-node() external;
```

That check fails unfortunately. To my understanding this has to do with the map:map structure not carrying through the document node.

Is there a good way of going around it? I could use *xdmp:unqote* but it feels a bit messy. I could also put into the database but doing document inserts and deletions just for that feels like a bit much overhead.

Any thoughts on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: what you want is to use `map:entry()` instead of
`map:map()`.  The following returns true (that is, it stores a document
node as the value of the key `"key"` in the map):

```xquery
let $doc := document { <foobar/> }
let $map := map:entry('key', $doc)
return
   map:get($map, 'key') instance of document-node()
```

So what is the difference with the following, which stores an element
node instead?

```xquery
let $doc := document { <foobar/> }
let $map := map:map(
      <map:map xmlns:map='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map'>
         <map:entry>
            <map:key>key</map:key>
            <map:value>{ $doc }</map:value>
         </map:entry>
      </map:map>)
return
   map:get($map, 'key') instance of element()
```

The difference is that the above code first copies the document node to an
XML tree.  That XML tree is what gets passed as an argument to the function.
A document node added to an element is just "ignored", its
children get copied directly, as per the XDM recommendation.  This XML
tree is used as an XML representation of a map, and "deserialized".
What is in the element `map:value` **IS** an element node at this point,
so ends up as such in the map.

This might be more clear if we get rid of all the map machinery:

```xquery
let $doc  := document { <foobar/> }
let $elem := <value>{ $doc }</value>
return
   $elem/node() instance of element()
```

The value of `$elem` in this last code is the following (which makes
sense, right?, what else could it be, since document nodes cannot be
children of any other nodes?):

```xquery
<value>
   <foobar/>
</value>
```